# Sharing internet through a wireless ad-hoc in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection, ad-hoc-network

I'm actually requesting a workaround to share a PPoE wired Internet connection between two laptops using wireless.

I've tried sharing it the usual way... New Ad-hoc => Click turn On sharing => etc.
I've tried changing all the settings I could find related to the two networks on both machines.

Conclusion: Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Is it really buggy, or are my hands growing from the wrong place?
I'm almost sure I'm not the only one having this kind of problem.

What is the easiest/correct workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/). It should fit your bill.